# vuetify.js how to add type="submit" to Loaders Button

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

i am new in Vuetify.js im trying to make submit Form using **Loaders Button**
i tryid but it not worked.

**my tryid code**

```
       <v-btn
        rounded
        class="ma-2"
        type="submit"
        :loading="loading2"
        :disabled="loading2"
        color="primary"
        @click="loader = 'loading2'"
      >
        Login
        <template v-slot:loader>
          <span>Loading...</span>
        </template>
      </v-btn>
```

**my main code**

> ```
> <template>
>   <v-row justify="center">
>     <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
>       <form @submit.prevent="submit">
>         <v-card ref="form">
>           <v-card-text>
>             <h3 class="text-center">Login</h3>
>             <v-divider class="mt-3"></v-divider>
>
>             <v-col cols="12">
>               <v-img
>                 :src="require('@/assets/1.png')"
>                 class="my-3"
>                 contain
>                 height="80"
>               />
>             </v-col>
>
>             <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
>               <v-text-field
>                 v-model.trim="form.mobile_number"
>                 type="number"
>                 label="Mobile No"
>                 solo
>                 autocomplete="off"
>               ></v-text-field>
>               <small class="form-text red--text" v-if="errors.mobile_number">{{
>                 errors.mobile_number[0]
>               }}</small>
>             </v-col>
>
>             <v-col cols="12">
>               <v-text-field
>                 v-model.trim="form.password"
>                 type="password"
>                 label="Password"
>                 solo
>                 autocomplete="off"
>                 append-icon="mdi-eye"
>               ></v-text-field>
>               <small class="form-text red--text" v-if="errors.password">{{
>                 errors.password[0]
>               }}</small>
>             </v-col>
>           </v-card-text>
>
>           <v-divider class="mt-12"></v-divider>
>
>           <v-card-actions>
>             <div class="text-center">
>               <v-btn
>                 rounded
>                 color="primary"
>                 dark
>                 to="/AppMain/UserRegisterPage"
>                 nuxt
>                 >Register</v-btn
>               >
>             </div>
>
>             <v-spacer></v-spacer>
>
>             <div class="text-center">
>               <v-btn
>                 rounded
>                 class="ma-2"
>                 type="submit"
>                 :loading="loading2"
>                 :disabled="loading2"
>                 color="primary"
>                 @click="loader = 'loading2'"
>               >
>                 Login
>                 <template v-slot:loader>
>                   <span>Loading...</span>
>                 </template>
>               </v-btn>
>
>               <!-- <v-btn rounded type="submit" color="primary" dark>Login</v-btn> -->
>             </div>
>           </v-card-actions>
>         </v-card>
>       </form>
>     </v-col>
>   </v-row>
>  </template>
>  <script>
>  export default {
>   middleware: ["guest"],
>   data() {
>     return {
>       loader: null,
>       loading: false,
>       loading2: false,
>       loading3: false,
>       loading4: false,
>       loading5: false,
>       form: {
>         mobile_number: "",
>         password: "",
>       },
>     };
>   },
>   watch: {
>     loader() {
>       const l = this.loader;
>       this[l] = !this[l];
>
>       setTimeout(() => (this[l] = false), 3000);
>
>       this.loader = null;
>     },
>   },
>   methods: {
>     async submit() {
>       await this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
>         data: this.form,
>       });
>
>       this.$router.push("/");
>     },
>   },
> };
> </script>
> <style>
> .custom-loader {
>   animation: loader 1s infinite;
>   display: flex;
> }
> @-moz-keyframes loader {
>   from {
>     transform: rotate(0);
>   }
>   to {
>     transform: rotate(360deg);
>   }
> }
> @-webkit-keyframes loader {
>   from {
>     transform: rotate(0);
>   }
>   to {
>     transform: rotate(360deg);
>   }
> }
> @-o-keyframes loader {
>   from {
>     transform: rotate(0);
>   }
>   to {
>     transform: rotate(360deg);
>   }
> }
> @keyframes loader {
>   from {
>     transform: rotate(0);
>   }
>   to {
>     transform: rotate(360deg);
>   }
> }
> </style>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You create and use the variable "loading" but never set it.

For resolve your problem, please, add in your @click method something like

```
loading = true
....
```

and then make loading same to false, for stop the loading style of your button.

Good luck!